# ionic slides in vertical direction rather than horizontal

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make Ionic slides vertical, not horizontally?

So, instead it drags/animates from left/right, I want it up/down.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ionic Slides are based on [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com). As you can read in their [Api Documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters), there is a Option called `direction`, which can be **horizontal** or **vertical**.

These Options can passed to the `<ion-slides>` via the Options like this:

```html
<ion-slides [options]="sliderOptions">
    ...
</ion-slides>
```

***.html**

```js
sliderOptions = {
    direction: 'vertival'
}
```

***.ts**